# Finding optimal subspace for Linear Discriminant Analysis - Elements of Statistical Learning 4.3.3

Tags: regression, machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, covariance, dimensionality-reduction

Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) possibly operates a dimension reduction. Section 4.3.3 in Elements of Statistical Learning explicits this notion as well as a method for computing the "optimal subspace for LDA".

https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/ESLII.pdf

Assuming $K$ classes, for a new observation $x$ LDA computes $\min_{k}{\|(\hat{\mu}_{k}^{*}-x^{*})\|^{2}}$ where $x^{*}$ and $\hat{\mu}_{k}^{*}$ are transformation of input $x$ and centroid $\hat{\mu}_{k}$ of class $k$ in a ad-hoc basis. In other terms we look for $k$ minimizing the distance of input data to the closest centroid (see more details [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/405541/computation-of-lda-in-elements-of-statistical-learning-4-3-2)).

The $k$ centroids lie in an affine subspace of dimension at most $K-1$. (This is geometry, for $K=2$ we can say that two points uniquely define a line, which is of dimension $K-1=2-1=1$.) We might project $X^{*}$ onto this centroid-spanning subspace $H_{K-1}$ and compare distances there. For $p$-dimensional inputs, if $p$ is much larger than $K$ this will mean considerable drop in dimension.

Further we might pick a subspace $H_{L}\subseteq{H_{K-1}}$ of dimension $L<K-1$ which is optimal in some sense.

> Fisher defined optimal to
>   mean that the projected centroids were spread out as much as possible in
>   terms of variance.

Then Elements of Statiscal Learning explicits the following method for finding the optimal subspace

> • compute the $K \times p$ matrix of class centroids $M$ and the common
>   covariance matrix $W$ (for within-class covariance);
>
> • compute $M^{∗} = MW^{−1/2}$ using the eigen-decomposition of $W$;
>
> • compute $B^{∗}$, the covariance matrix of $M^{∗}$ ($B$ for between-class covariance), and its eigen-decomposition $B^{∗} = V^{∗}DBV^{∗T}$.
>
> The columns
>   $v_{l}^{∗}$ of $V^{∗}$ in sequence from first to last define the coordinates of the
>   optimal subspaces.

What is the rationale behind this method, and how is it providing the optimal subspace for LDA as per Fisher's definition of optimality ? More precisely :

• Why are $W$ the within-class and $B^{*}$ between-class covariance matrices ?

• Why do the columns $v_{l}^{*}$of $V^{*}$ define the coordinate of the optimal subspaces ?

• How do we derive the discriminant variables ?

Comment: Not necessarily a direct answer, but could be helpful https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/48859/3277

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Within-class, between-class covariance matrices***

• Assuming common covariance matrix $\hat{\Sigma}=\hat{\Sigma}_{k}$ for all classes $k$ we write

$\hat{\Sigma}=\sum_{k=1}^{K}\sum_{g_{i}=k}{(x_{i}-\hat{\mu}_{k})(x_{i}-\hat{\mu}_{k})^{T}/(N-K)}$

where the centroid $\hat{\mu}_{k}$ is a $p$-vector estimated by $\hat{\mu}_{k}=\sum_{g_{i}=k}x_{i}/N_{k}$ and $N_{k}$ the number of elements of $X$ (the number of observations) in class $k$.

$\hat{\Sigma}$ measures the dispersion of observations around the mean of the class they belong to. We call $\hat{\Sigma}$ the *within-class covariance*. We denote $\hat{\Sigma}=W$.

• $M$ is the $K \times p$ matrix of centroids $\hat{\mu}_{k}$ so that its covariance matrix is given by

$\sum_{k=1}^{K}(\hat{\mu}_{k}-\bar{\mu})(\hat{\mu}_{k}-\bar{\mu})^{T}/K$

with $\bar{\mu}$ the mean of centroids $\hat{\mu}_{K}$ with $k=1..K$. It measures the dispersion of the centroids around the mean of all centroids and we call it the *between-class covariance*. We denote $E[M^{T}M]=B$.

• We transform $M$ into $M^{*}=MW^{-1/2}$, which operates a some basis change ( close to a [whitening or sphering transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitening_transformation) ). I explain in the next section the rationale behind the choice for this basis. $M^{*}$ has a covariance matrix $B^{*}$.

***Optimal subspace***

Fisher's approach to LDA maximizes the criterion

$J(w)=w^{T}Bw / w^{T}Ww$.

We minimize the within-class covariance and maximize the between-class covariance.

$J(w)$ is invariant w.r.t. rescaling of $w \leftarrow \alpha w$, so that we can choose $\alpha$ as to have a unit denominator $w^{T}Ww=1$ ( since it is a scalar ). Thus we can turn the optimization problem into solving

$\max_{w}  \frac{1}{2} w^{T}Bw$  s. t. $w^{T}Ww=1$.

Which we can rewrite after the convenient basis change $w^{*} \leftarrow W^{1/2}w$ :

$\min_{w}   -\frac{1}{2}(w^{*})^{T}B^{*}w^{*}$  s. t. $(w^{*})^{T}w^{*}=1$.

The Lagrangien for this problem writes

$L = -\frac{1}{2}(w^{*})^{T}B^{*}w^{*} + \frac{1}{2}\lambda[(w^{*})^{T}w^{*}-1]$

and the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions give

$B^{*}w^{*}=\lambda w^{*}$.

We see here that the basis change we operated enable to write KKT conditions for our optimization problem as an eigendecomposition. We can then write $B^{*}=V^{*}D_{B}(V^{*})^{T}$ where the columns $v_{l}^{*}$ of $V^{*}$ are the eigenvectors of $B^{*}$ and the diagonal values of $D_{B}$ its eigenvalues.

From the objective function $J(w)$ we see that the directions we look for correspond to the largest eigenvalues. Indeed under KKT conditions we have

$J(w^{*})=-\frac{1}{2}(w^{*})^{T}B^{*}w^{*}=-\frac{1}{2}(w^{*})^{T}\lambda w^{*}=-\lambda/2$

since $(w^{*})^{T}w^{*}=1$.

Finally, back to the original basis, discriminant variables are defined as $Z_{l}=v_{l}^{T}X$ with $v_{l}=W^{-1/2}v_{l}^{*}$ for $l=1..L$ corresponding to the $L$ eigenvectors $v^{*}_{l}$ with largest eigenvalue in the decomposition of the transformed between-class matrix $B^{*}$.

[More information here.](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/273ASpring09/Fisher-LDA.pdf)